# Changing pandas index to column headings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with my index as years, and one column of integer entries.
I want to change my index into column headings.
I have this structure for several small dataframes, which I will attach to a larger dataframe.

```
         1
0         
2021  4365
2020  5812
2019  6773
2018  6681
2017  6809
2016  6776
2015  6587
2014  5978
```

How can I turn this into:

```
       2021 2020 2019 2018 2017 2016 2015 2014
Amount 4365 5812 6773 6681 6809 6776 6587 5978
```

I'm afraid I don't know where to begin, and I can't find any examples of this online. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have your `df`:

```
print(df)

         1
0         
2021  4365
2020  5812
2019  6773
2018  6681
2017  6809
2016  6776
2015  6587
2014  5978
```

And used `T` to transpose, and `pandas.DataFrame.rename` the index.

```
res = df.T
res.rename(index={1: "Amount"},inplace=True)

print(res)

        2021  2020  2019  2018  2017  2016  2015  2014
Amount  4365  5812  6773  6681  6809  6776  6587  5978
```

Perhaps this gets you what you need.

Comment: Thank you for the simple explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Did you transpose your dataframe?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([1,2],[3,4])
print(df.T)
```